# Program on Swift Crashes when first compiling

Tags: swift

So I ran this code using swift and the issue that I am having is that it's not working on the first try it compiles the project. However, when I stop the project and run it again it works perfectly fine and I do repeat this several times and the issue doesn't occur anymore. More specifically, when the project opens and I press a button on the app it goes to the error that I show below:

This is the error that I get when I run it for the first time

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an
>   error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “.tmp”
>   couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/.tmp, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000335d9b0 {Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}"

This error shows up on the line where let contentstring is created. I check the value of contentstring and I get that contentstring = (NSString) 0x0000000000000000. When running the program multiple times it gives me a valid value and it works perfectly fine.

I am not sure why this error occurs only once when the button is pressed and what is a solid approach to this problem.

```
import UIKit

class KresgePorter: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

   var printString: String!

   var array: [String] = []

   var count: Int = 0

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
               var nameTXT = ""
               var documentsDir = ""

               let website = some string url

               guard let url1 = URL(string: website) else { return  }

               //This portion of the code focuses on creating a download task with a completion handler
               //Completion handler moves the downloaded file to the app's directory

               let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url1) {
                   urlOrNil, responseOrNil, errorOrNil in
                   // check for and handle errors:
                   // * errorOrNil should be nil
                   // * responseOrNil should be an HTTPURLResponse with statusCode in 200..<299
                   print("Went into the let\n")
                   guard let fileURL = urlOrNil else { return }
                   do {
                       let documentsURL = try
                           FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                   in: .userDomainMask,
                                                   appropriateFor: nil,
                                                   create: true)
                       let savedURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileURL.lastPathComponent)
                       let filename = fileURL.lastPathComponent
                       let fileName2 = URL(fileURLWithPath: filename).deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
                       nameTXT = fileName2
                       print("the content of nameTXT is: \(nameTXT)")

                       try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: fileURL, to: savedURL)
                   } catch {
                       print ("file error: \(error)")
                   }
                   let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
                   documentsDir = paths.firstObject as! String
                   print("Path to the Documents directory\n\(documentsDir)")

               }
               downloadTask.resume()


               //If you want to receive progress updates as the download proceeds, you must use a delegate.
               var urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self as? URLSessionDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)

               func startDownload(url1: URL){
                   print("Went into the startDownload function\n")
                   let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url1)
                   //let fname = downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename
                   downloadTask.resume()
               }

               startDownload(url1: url1)

       /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
               usleep(270000)

               let directPath = documentsDir + "/" + nameTXT + ".tmp"
               let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: directPath)
               let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

               printString = contentString as String

               let fullName = printString
               array = fullName!.components(separatedBy: "\n")


       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return array.count

   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "breakfast", for: indexPath)
       cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
       return cell

   }
```

}

Comment: `usleep(270000)` is probably a bad to start with - you should be reacting a known state, not "guessing" at how long it might take.  You should also verify that the file exists before reading it.  At a guess `documentsDir` and or `nameTXT` are still empty when you try and open the file.  This is where you should be using a callback of some kind to return these values directly.

Answer (score 1):

I shouldn't use `try!` in production code!

```
let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

convert to this:

```
do {
    let contentString = try? String( url, encoding: .utf8)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The actual problem is that:

```
let directPath = documentsDir + "/" + nameTXT + ".tmp"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: directPath)
```

yields `"/.tmp"`. this is an invalid URL.

This is because of both `documentsDir` and `nameTXT` are empty.

So, the core reason is that you call

```
let directPath = documentsDir + "/" + nameTXT + ".tmp"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: directPath)
```

outside of the server response callback.

Just move your code from

```
// If you want to receive progress updates as the download until 
array = fullName!.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

into closure right after this line:

```
print("Path to the Documents directory\n\(documentsDir)")
```

your closure is launched asynchronously.

Comment: And apparently `directPath` is valid when restarting the app.

Comment: So I took the portion of the code // If you want to receive progress updates as the download until 
array = fullName!.components(separatedBy: "\n") and placed it under print("Path to the Documents directory\n\(documentsDir)"). However, the values weren't displayed into the app